# Getting some symbolic characters when parsing xml using Fuzi

Tags: xml, parsing, swift4

I am using [Fuzi for xml parsing](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) and [Alamofire for getting response from server](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). I got my xml response from server like below:-

XML:

```
<urlset xmlns:xhtml="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; xmlns="sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">; 
<items> 
<title> [Hindi] लखनऊ, वाराणसी, पटना, गया</title> 
<articledate>16 Feb, 2017</articledate> 
</items> 
</urlset>
```

It has other language contents in hindi (indian language) as mentioned in above XML block.

When I print, it prints English characters properly but other languages not, it prints some symbolic characters like below: -

Code: -

```
Alamofire.request("My_xml_URL").responseString { response in
            guard let xml = try? XMLDocument(string: response.value ?? "") else {
                return
            }
            guard let feed = xml.root else {
                return
            }
            for entry in feed.children(tag: "items") {
                let title = entry.firstChild(tag: "title")?.stringValue ?? ""    
                print(title)   // it prints symbolic response here
            }
        }
```

Output

```
▿ Optional<String> - some : "[Hindi] à¤²à¤à¤¨à¤, à¤µà¤¾à¤°à¤¾à¤£à¤¸à¥, à¤ªà¤à¤¨à¤¾, à¤à¤¯à¤¾ à¤®à¥à¤ à¤" –
```

Please help, how can I resolve it.

Comment: This means one of two things, either the output encoding is not UTF-8, or the output device does not have a Hindi font, or maybe even both.

Comment: Device is able to display Hindi font. How can I set UTF-8 with Fuzi lib.

Comment: Read the documentation for the library?